# Get Id from cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

In the Cloudwatch log, it has been logged like this via Lambda:

```
START RequestId: 14699111-bd51-11fa-9dfd-00eee6d18c52
OrderId: 111111
Task: Create
ERROR OrderId: undefined
END RequestId: 14699111-bd51-11fa-9dfd-00eee6d18c52

START RequestId: 14699222-bd51-11fa-9dfd-00eee61f8c52
OrderId: 22222
Task: Create
ERROR OrderId: undefined
END RequestId: 146992222-bd51-11fa-9dfd-00eee61f8c52
```

Is it possible to use Cloudwatch Insights or any tools to query `OrderId: undefined` then attempt to get `OrderId: xxxxx` between START and END logs event?

Expected Result example:

```
OrderId: 111111
OrderId: 22222
```

Comment: Just prefix the logs with `RequestId`

Comment: @jellycsc Sorry i don't understand what you mean, can you provide an example of query using Cloudwatch Insights

Comment: I mean instead of logging `OrderId: 111111`, you can log `[14699111-bd51-11fa-9dfd-00eee6d18c52] OrderId: 111111`. By doing this, you can search by the request id.